# Default_backend not defined in cryptography-RSA (python)

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I am getting default_backend is not defined error while using RSA algorithm from hazmat in python 3.5 . Can anyone solve my problem ? The problem occurs while creating private key for rsa algorithm using cryptography module in python.

Comment: Did you use `module.func` or `func`? If the first you need to have written `from module import func` else you need the module prefix after using `import module` can you show us your code, please?

Comment: You must show your code if you want help debugging it. It's one of our rules.

Answer (score 1):

you should have post your code to tell you your mistake. I think you are not passing the `default_backend` to ec to generate the private key. here is the implementation:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec

class Wallet:
    def __init__(self):
        
        # SECP=standard efficient cryptography prime. prime is used to genereate the curve
        # that prime number is 256 bit, K=kobler, 1 stands for first
        self.private_key=ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP256K1(), default_backend())
        self.public_key=self.private_key.public_key()
```